# Nothing appears when I apply an XSLT stylesheet to an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a simple educational project for learning the XSLT language, but when I try to apply the style sheet to the XML file the transformation  returns me a blank HTML page, what you think is the error in the code linked later?
(using XMLSpear as editor)

here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "teilite.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stile.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Ettore Fieramosca o la disfida di Barletta : racconto</title>
                <respStmt>
                    <resp>Conversione TEI P5 a cura di</resp>
                    <name>V. Caproni</name>
                </respStmt>
            </titleStmt>
            <publicationStmt>
                <publisher>Exercise Press</publisher>
                <date>20-10-2014</date>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <bibl>
                    <title>title</title>
                    <author>author</author>
                    <publisher>publisher</publisher>
                    <date>1856</date>
                    <from>title of the book</from>
                    <licence>link to the licence</licence>
                </bibl>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
        <encodingDesc>
            <styleDefDecl scheme="css"/>
            <tagsDecl>
                <rendition xml:id="blue">color: blue;</rendition>
                <rendition xml:id="red">color: red;</rendition> 
            </tagsDecl>
        </encodingDesc> 
    </teiHeader>
    <text>
       <front>
          <p>author name</p>
            <p>title</p>
       </front>
        <epigraph>
           <p>epigraph n1</p>
        </epigraph>
        <epigraph>
           epigraph n2
        </epigraph>
        <body>
           <div type="Capitolo" xml:id="cap1">
              <h2>Capitolo I</h2>
            <p rendition="#blue">
        sometext
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

here is the xls code

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="tei:TEI">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Ettore Fieramosca o La Disfida di Barletta</title>
    <link href="stile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
<body>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:teiHeader">
  <br/>
  <h1>Informazioni sul documento</h1>
  <br/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="tei:front">
    <br/>
    <h1>Frontespizio e prefazione</h1> <br/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tei:front">
<br/>
<h1>Frontespizio e prefazione</h1> <br/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT
nothing is shown either in the built-in browser or in firefox or chrome

EDIT 2
According to the built-in xsl and xml validator both the document are well formed

Comment: which browser ? Chrome won't allow multiple local files to communicate for security reason. Try with firefox and inspect the "blank page" and you might see the xml converted if there were no errors.

Comment: So is the problem happening when you run it in XMLSpear, or when you view it in a browser? Is there a need for that DTD that the XML file uses?

Comment: Post updated "nothing is shown in either the built-in browser or in firefox or chrome in"

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Visual Studio. Please try removing the DTD and see if that helps.

Comment: @JLRishe thank you, removing the dtd solved the problem, do you know the reason?

Comment: Was the DTD file placed in a location where your browser could access it? If not, that could have prevented it from processing the XML. That would be my best guess. A DTD is not needed to apply XSLT to a document, so I would say most of the time it's best to just not use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the presence of the DTD in the source XML was causing this failure. A DTD is not usually needed in order to transform XML through XSLT, so unless there's a specific reason to have one, you can just leave it out of the XML.

Most likely, the DTD was not in the same folder as the XML and when the browser tried to load it, it was not there so the browser simply refused to process the XML at all.